# Rotating rectangles so they maintain their relative position to the canvas

Tags: algorithm, math, rotation

I have a background pixmap, basically a canvas, which I draw a bunch of
rectangles on and I need to rotate the pixmap and rectangles.
However rotating the background pixmap and the rectangles needs to be done
seperately, that is the rotation of the background pixmap gets handled via an
external library routine and I need to rotate and redraw the rectangles
on top manually.

So far I am actually able to rotate the rectangles by applying a
[transformation matrix I got from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Rotation)
to each vertex. What I don't know is how to translate them that each rectangle retains its position relative to the canvas.

Here is a quick drawing for illustration of what I want to achieve:
[image]

I need to do this with C and Xlib, but I'm not necessarily looking for code but would appreciate some general hints/algorithms.

Comment: The transformation matrix you applied rotates the points about the origin. You need to make sure that the reference point about which you rotate is the same for the rectangle and the pixmap. Also please include all references and pictures in the question itself. We shouldn't need to go to external links.

Comment: It is not possible for me to directly include images with less than 10 rep points. If you look at the background pixmap (i.e. the black rectangle in the illustration), what would be the reference point of the rotation?

Comment: It is very difficult to guess until we see your code.

Comment: Well, there is not much to show, it is just a single API call asking for the Pixmap to be rotated n degrees. If I have a white Pixmap of 200x300 and ask for it to be rotated by 90 degrees I get back a white Pixmap of 300x200, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the translated position for the child object, you need to rotate the **relative position vector** for the child object, and then add it to the origin:

[image: Notice that the relative vector is rotated]

Pseudocode would be:

```
public static Vector2 OffsetByRotation(Vector2 childPos, Vector2 parentPos, float angle)
{
    var relativeVector = childPos - parentPos;
    relativeVector = Rotate(relativeVector, angle);
    return parentPos + relativeVector;
}
```

Note that your example image not only rotates the parent object, but also translates it: your left image is rotated around (0, 300), but this point is then translated to (0, 0).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the latter was the part I was missing, after applying the rotation I needed to translate by (height, 0) for positive and (0, width) for negative angles.